How to request HealthKit permissions for Scored Assessments (GAD-7/PHQ-7)?
In iOS 18.0 there is new HK type - HKScoredAssessment (subclassed by HKGAD7Assessment and HKPHQ9Assessment). When trying to save it to HealthKit I don't see how one can request authorization for it. By looking at the documentation it only seems like they added stateOfMindType() in iOS 18 (on HKObjectType).

It might not be that obvious since almost all other types have convenience methods (such as stateOfMindType()) or can be accessed by quantity/category type.
As it comes to the scored assessments it's possible create a HKObjectType by using HKScoredAssessmentType and passing the needed identifier.
e.g.:
let type: HKObjectType = HKScoredAssessmentType(.GAD7)


